# How to fire a trigger every 30 seconds from 2 pm to 11 pm in quartz using Java?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am using this statement -

```
trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                         .withIdentity("abc", "group1")
                         .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                                             .cronSchedule("0/30 0 14-23 * * ?"))
                         .build();
```

Somehow the trigger is fired at 2 pm, 2:00:30 pm and no more.
What is the problem?

Comment: May be you could add some logs

Comment: im trying that now,
but is my time expression correct ?

Comment: The [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is saying every 30 minutes (starting at 0 of the hour), every midnight, from the 14 to 23 day of the month of any month any day of the week.

Comment: so then what is the correct expession ?
if its 14 to 23 day, then why is it triggering at least once, today is not a day from 14-23

Comment: try CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/30 * 14-23 * * ?"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have put 0 in the minute field.So it fires only at 2:00.
Try

```
 trigger2 = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("abc", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(
                      CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/30 * 14-23 * * ?"))
                    .build();
```

Comment: Does this OP cron will run at 3:00:00? Am i right? i.e only when the minute turns `0`

Comment: @Octopus ya according to the documentation it shud run at 3pm also.http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: this worked !!
but what if i have to trigger from 2:30 pm till 12 am ??

Comment: i dont know this for sure.try 14-23,0 in the hours field

Answer (score 0):

From [quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/examples/Example3) documentation I extracted the following example:

**Job #1 is scheduled to run every 20 seconds**

```
JobDetail job = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", SimpleJob.class);
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1", "group1", "job1", "group1", "0/20 * * * * ?");
sched.addJob(job, true);
```

Adapting to your situation it should go like this:

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1", "group1", "job1", "group1", "0/30 * 14-23 * * ?");
```

Comment: shudn't that be 0/30.correct me if i am wrong @user503413